# CreateCriteria grails

Tags: grails

I am trying to use the create criteria method in grails but im getting back an empty list im not sure why.
My code is as follow

```
    def results = PostOrder.createCriteria().list() {
        posts{
            author{
                eq('username', lookupPerson().username)
            }
        }
        picture{
            user{
                eq('username', lookupPerson().username)
            }
        }
    }
```

PostOrder domain is as follows:

```
class PostOrder {

    String pOrder
    Date dateCreated
    Picture picture
    Post posts
    Video video
    Boolean favorite = false

    static hasMany = [children : Child]

    static constraints = {
        picture nullable: true
        posts nullable: true
        video nullable:  true
    }
}
```

Post is as follows:

```
 class Post {

    String message
    User author
    Date dateCreated
    Child child
    boolean postedToAll
    String tag

static hasMany = [tags:Tag]

    static constraints = {
        child nullable: true
        tags nullable: true
        tag nullable: true
     }
}
```

finally picture is as follows:

```
 class Picture {

    String orgName
    String urlOrg
    String urlWeb
    String urlThumb
    Date   dateCreated
    String caption
    Child child
    User user
    Album contained
    String tag
    boolean postedToAll

    static hasMany = [tags:Tag]

    static constraints = {
        orgName blank: false
        caption maxSize: 500
        tags nullable:  true
        caption nullable: true
        tag nullable: true
        child nullable:  true
    }
}
```

To me this would work perfectly fine, can anyone see why is doesn't?

Comment: What do you want to find? Try to remove either posts or picture and see the result.

Comment: im wanting to get all PostOrder instances where the author in posts equals current user and where the user in picture equals current user

Comment: Make sure that you have a post with pictures. Also is good to enable hibernate sql output, then you can see the query that GORM are running. This can be done in `DataSource.groovy`, by adding `logSql=true` in the `dataSource{}` block.

Comment: You're getting an empty list - are you sure that that answer is wrong?  i.e. are you running this query inside a unit/integration test or against a real database?  Do you have data that actually matches the query you're running?

Answer (score 0):

Does it have the same username in both pictures and posts??? 
If not, you have to surround them with and or{} because by default it is used the and logical

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add a logical block (and/or) like this:

```
def results = PostOrder.createCriteria().list() {
    or {
        posts{
            author{
                eq('username', lookupPerson().username)
            }
        }
        picture{
            user{
                eq('username', lookupPerson().username)
            }
        }
    }
}
```